# How to connect Excel to Oracle with PowerQuery

Tags: excel, oracle, odbc, powerquery, odac

I am trying to connect Excel to my company's Oracle Database. According to the following instructions it should be fairly easy: https://www.wikihow.com/Connect-Excel-to-an-Oracle-Database.

However it has been impossible and quite frustrating so far.

I have followed two different approaches that I've found online.

**FIRST APPROACH: installed ODAC from Oracle's Universal Installer**

I went to this site https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/dotnet-odacdev-downloads.html and downloaded the `ODAC 12.2.0.1.1` file.

Then, I went through the installation process basically just clicking 'next' on every step.

Note 1: (I don't know if this might be important), in the Database Connection configuration tab I **did not** fill in any of the information (simply because I didn't know what to put there). It said that if information wasn't filled in, it **would not create the TNSNAMES.ORA file**.

Note 2: After finishing the installation it says 'run the SQL scripts located in the ... directory after the install'. Which I didn't do, again, because I didn't know how.

After the installation finished a directory was created in the following location: `C:\app\client\myUserName\`.
The directory goes all the way down to `C:\app\client\myUserName\product\12.2.0\client_1`, and it contains a bunch of files and folders.

I noticed that **no environmental variable was created**.

**SECOND APPROACH: installed ODBC instant client**

I went to this site https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html and downloaded both `instantclient-basic-windows.x64-19.6.0.0.0dbru.zip` and `instantclient-odbc-windows.x64-19.6.0.0.0dbru.zip`.

Then I created the directory `C:\Oracle\instantclient_19_6` and unziped both folders contents into it.

Finally, I ran odbc_install from the command_line, as an administrator, but got `Oracle ODBC Driver with same name already exists`.

Note: in this case I also noticed that **no environmental variable was created**.

**RESULTS**:

When I go to Excel and click on `Data\From Database\From Oracle Database` I keep getting the same error as before: **The recommended provider ('Oracle.DataAccess.Client') is not installed. You can continue with your current provider, however it has been deprecated and may not work properly."**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by installing the 64 bits version of Oracle's client. Its located at https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/112010-win64soft.html, file `win64_11gR2_client.zip`.

Although the message *"The recommended provider ('Oracle.DataAccess.Client') is not installed. You can continue with your current provider, however it has been deprecated and may not work properly."* remained, I was able to connect after ignoring it.

Comment: PS: win64_11gR2_client.zip is Oracle's Universal Installer.

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried a bunch of approaches and finally got rid of the 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client is not installed' error.

Install Oracle Client for Microsoft Tools:

ODP.NET, Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (Code), and ODAC
https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/net-downloads.html

> Oracle Client for Microsoft Tools installs and configures ODP.NET to support 64-bit Microsoft tool connections with Oracle database. It supports connecting with Power BI Desktop, Power BI service, Excel, SQL Server Analysis Services, SQL Server Data Tools, SQL Server Integration Services, SQL Server Reporting Services, and BizTalk Server.

I have installed Oracle Client for Microsoft Tools 19.17 for (Microsoft Windows x64 (64-bit)) (`V1032890-01.exe`).

Alternatively, you could follow the learn more link:

Connect Microsoft Tools to Oracle Databases
https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/ocmt.html

Tutorials > Power BI Desktop: Connect to Oracle Database
https://www.oracle.com/a/ocom/docs/database/microsoft-powerbi-connection-adw.pdf